# How to configure morbo with https interface?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I am using Mojolicious for a web application.

Can I configure morbo with https interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start morbo with

```
 morbo -l 'https://*:3000' App.pl
```

to listen for https connections. You can also specify certificates like so:

```
 morbo -l 'https://*:3000?cert=certs/server.crt&key=certs/server.key&ca=certs/root.crt' App.pl
```

See https://docs.mojolicious.org/morbo

Answer (score 0):

I'd just like to note that Morbo is a development web server, and not meant for running your application once it's in production. Other than that see answer from clamp.